# Android listview wont load images

Tags: android, listview

i have listview , and in each row needs to be an hoeizontal scrollview witch N number of images , and its just keeps crashing my app as soon as i start that activity

here is the code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.foto_list_row, null);
    }


    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.foto_title); // title


    HashMap<String, String> n = new HashMap<String, String>();
    n = data.get(position);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.fotoh);
    String var[] = (n.get(FotoView.TAG_ALBUM)).split(",");
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(activity.getApplicationContext());
    for(int a=0;a<var.length;a++){
        String t = var[a];
        if(t == "null"){
            t.replace("null", "");
        }else{
            //tv.setText(t);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(t,iv);
            ll.addView(iv);
        }
    }


    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(n.get(FotoView.TAG_TITLE));
    return vi;
}
```

Comment: problem is with your adapter ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you probably want is to have a Gallery in a xml layout file, and that file wil serve as the ListView row and you need to create another Adapter for the Gallery in your current in getView() you need to do this.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    Gallery gallery;
    if (convertView == null)
        gallery == inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_row, parent, false);
    else 
        gallery == (Gallery) convertView;

    String[] images = data.get(position).split(",");
    GalleryAdapter gAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(images);
    gallery.setAdapter(gAdapter);

    return gallery;

}
```

I think with this you can have a basic idea what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

just search "world of listview" in google you will get answer how to create custom adapter for list type in android